# Как сделать кнопку "мне нравится" для статьи WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Появилась задача создать кнопку "мне нравится".

Основные моменты

1. Кнопка должна иметь количество лайков для каждого поста
2. Кнопку можно нажимать/ снимать с определенного IP , т.е 2 лайка с 1 ип - нельзя ( можно сделать и другие проверки, буду рад новым идеям )

Дилемма в том, каким образом это сделать. Не прошу кода, а лишь идей, алгоритма, как лучше сделать.

Можно было бы добавить для поста через ACF поля, которые будут иметь значения кол. лайков, но тогда как изменять в базе данных при клике + как сделать проверку по ip/компьютеру, или другим аспектам (не хотелось бы делать проверку через localstorage/cookie).

Comment: Если ты хочешь проверять на ip, то список этих ip нужно хранить где-то. Создавай таблицу post_id, ip. Где при голосовании проверяй ее и записывай проголосовавшего, а затем обновляй постмету.

Comment: А есть другие варианты кроме IP?

Comment: Есть. Готовые плагины. Если религия или иные причины не позволяют их использовать, то можно посмотреть их код.

Comment: @SeVlad просматривать их код тоже не позволяет религия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Создайте таблицу в базе данных с колонками post_id и IP
- Сделайте вывод кнопки в своей функции, поместите её в `functions.php` темы или в свой плагин. Кнопка должна иметь `data-id` с id поста
- При выводе кнопки получите IP из $_SERVER и проверьте значение в базе. Если есть - кнопку вывести disabled, показать значок нравится закрашенным
- Навесьте на эту функцию шорткод - может пригодиться
- Создайте свой js-скрипт для обработки нажатия на кнопку. Запускайте его через wp_enqueue_script()
- Добавьте в шаблон поста (например, `single.php`) вывод кнопки
- По клику на кнопку в вашем скрипте запускайте ajax, отправляя им id поста из data-id
- В php-обработчике ajax определите IP из переменной $_SERVER. Проверьте, есть ли в базе запись с id поста и IP. Если есть - заканчиваем обработку.
- Запишите значение IP и id в базу
- Верните в js результат проверки. Если кнопка не была ранее нажата, закрасьте её, показав, что "нравится" сработало.

Comment: Спасибо большое за отличный алгоритм создания

Comment: Такой вопрос, не возникнет ли сложностей по мере роста этой таблицы. Ведь на хорошо посещаемом ресурсе строк в этой таблице уже через месяц будет превышать 30k, а через год 300k как минимум, а через 2 года и т.д.. Не сложно ли будет искать по такому количеству строк?

Comment: @user242682 я работал с базами, содержащими десятки миллионов строк в одной таблице. Проблем не будет. Столбцы маленькие, плюс индексация.

Comment: @KAGG Design я реализовал предложенный вами способ, но появилась проблема. Вернее просто не совершенство данного метода. Суть заключается в том что IP имеют свойство меняться в том случае если они динамические, а это большинство юзеров но даже не в этом основная беда, с мобильным интернетом все еще хуже там ip меняется еще чаще, а мобильных юзеров 60-70% трафика. Вот теперь думаю как все это дело усовершенствовать что бы получить чуть большую точность, может быть есть какие нибудь мысли?

Comment: @user242682 Ваш комментарий выходит очень далеко за рамки изначального вопроса. Задайте новый вопрос на Stackoverflow.

Comment: @KAGG Design я задавал вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1153988/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-cookie-wordpress) правда на тот момент я толком не знал как реализовать поэтому спрашивал больше про cookie или лучше вообще новый вопрос задать?

Comment: @user242682 лучше новый, потому что идентификация пользователя - это не про куки.